# Diameter Gy interface

Tags: c

In diameter Gy interface is it optional to have sub AVP inside trigger AVP? Trigger AVP is part of MSCC AVP. If child AVP of trigger AVP (1264) are optional how we can make it as generic in our code to skip length check after decoding it's header.

Comment: Can you clarify your question and share parts of your code you have problems with?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).